# codeigniter uri segment url appending at the end

Tags: javascript, uri, segments

url : `http://localhost/back-office/index.php/staff/shopping`

when i change the category on every onchange event i want the url should be like this

```
http://localhost/back-office/index.php/staff/shopping/1
http://localhost/back-office/index.php/staff/shopping/2
```

for that i wrote javascript on change event

```
function cat()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('cat').value;   
    document.location = "shopping/" + x;


}


     <select name="cate" id="cat" onchange="cat()">
        <option value="0">Select Cateogry</option>
        <?php 
        foreach($get_cat as $category)
        {
            echo "<option value=$category->categoryid>$category->category</option>";            
        }
        ?>    
    </select>
```

the javscript works , but the url getting appended like

```
http://localhost/back-office/index.php/staff/shopping/shopping/2

http://localhost/back-office/index.php/staff/shopping/shopping/shopping/shopping/shopping/shopping/1
```

on every cagetory drop box onchange event the url is getting appended like this at the end.

how could i solve this

Comment: This is a javascript question, not codeigniter specific. Can you edit your tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specifically code your url..try this

```
function cat()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('cat').value;   
    url  = "http://localhost/back-office/index.php/staff/shopping/" + x;
    window.location = url;

}
```